# Bootstrap: In a modal dialog, how do I make the dropdown menu expand outside the dialog?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Example code:

http://jsfiddle.net/vpg5g/

I'd like to have the menu that drops down from the button expand over the modal's borders. As you see, the current state is unusable. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just make the modal dialog larger?

Comment: The number of items in the dropdown menu is dynamic, so I'd have to calculate the space I need. If I do that, I could also just write the links directly to the dialog, which is not really what I want.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The modal does not allow any overflowing, you can fix it by using :

```css
.modal { overflow: visible; }
.modal-body { overflow-y: visible; }
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vpg5g/1/)

You may want to add a class to apply those rules only to modals that really need it, in case this fix creates bugs.

Comment: If you have dialogs that have content that would normally cause the dialog to scroll (in other words, a buttload of content), then the content that would normally scroll will now overflow the dialog.

Comment: @villecoder You might have to adjust the height of the modal at some point, and trigger the scroll of the window rather than the scroll inside the modal.

Comment: @Sherbrow how to trigger the scroll of the window?

Comment: @PriteshAcharya Make the height of the modal bigger than the window. Unless some styles prevent the scroll, the normal scroll on the window will appear.

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot remove the overflow: auto
You can do something like this

```
    $('.drop-down-inside-modal').on('click' , '.dropdown-toggle', function(event){
        var self = $(this);
        var selfHeight = $(this).parent().height();
        var selfWidth = $(this).parent().width();
        var selfOffset = $(self).offset();
        var selfOffsetRigth = $(document).width() - selfOffset.left - selfWidth;
        var dropDown = self.parent().find('ul');
        $(dropDown).css({position:'fixed', top: selfOffset.top + selfHeight , left: 'auto', right: selfOffsetRigth ,  width: '160px'});
    });

    function fixDropdownPosition(){
        var openDropdownButton = $('.drop-down-inside-modal.open');
        if($(openDropdownButton).length){
            var selfHeight = $(openDropdownButton).height();
            var selfWidth = $(openDropdownButton).width();
            var openDropdownButtonOffset = $(openDropdownButton).offset();
            var openDropdownButtonOffsetRigth = $(document).width() - openDropdownButtonOffset.left - selfWidth;
            var openDropdown = $(openDropdownButton).find('ul');
            $(openDropdown).css({position:'fixed', top: openDropdownButtonOffset.top + selfHeight , left: 'auto' , right: openDropdownButtonOffsetRigth, width: '160px'});
        };
    };

    $(".modal-body").unbind("scroll");
    $(".modal-body").scroll(function(){
        fixDropdownPosition();
    });

    $( window ).resize(function() {
        fixDropdownPosition();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! glad someone find a use for this =)

Comment: This is a rather hacky solution and requires a lot of fixing up to be usable, but ultimately it was the only approach that got the job done for us.

Comment: I know it's hacky! but works fine, probably I could update it with a live example.

Comment: Coool gonna clean up my answer and make it easier to use